# simple macro on excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner to script macros. I want to validate a particular row. My requirement is IF all the cells has 'Y' in 20th row in Sheet2 then one of the cells in Sheet1 20th row should be updated as 'Y'.

How should I go about it? What will be the best approach?

Thanks for your guidance in advance.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Have you tried anything? Your question isn't very clear. Are there multiple columns involved in this row? Is there only one row?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how many cells are in the 20th row? Can you identify the cells to test?

I'm not sure that you need VBA for this; I think you could use the simple function:

```
=IF(COUNTA(Sheet2!$Y$1:$Y$5)=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$Y1:$Y5,"Y"),"Y","")
```

(updated based on OP's clarification.)
There are a couple of other ways to do it, but I think that is the simplest.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your response :)
There are 5 cells in 20th row. when a user updates all the 5 cells in 20th row as 'Y' then in sheet 1 20th row 'Y' should be displayed in any cell

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your responses :)
I have tried formula given by mehow its working fine.

```
=IF(AND(COUNTA(Sheet2!A20),COUNTA(Sheet2!B20),COUNTA(Sheet2!C20),COUNTA(Sheet2!D20),COUNTA(Sheet2!E20)), "Y", "N")
```

One more query is If value of A20 = 123, and B20 to D20 = 'Y' in sheet2, Then in sheet1 how to identify which cell in 'A' column has '123' and update 'B' column in the same row as 'Y'?

Do we need macros for this or can we do it with excel formulas??